# Semantic Menu - Need to put a centered Title

Tags: css, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I need to make my app title centered in the app Semantic menu.[image]

Below is my current code :

HTML:

```
<div class="ui red inverted borderless top attached menu">
  <div class="ui red dropdown icon launch button">
   <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
  </div>
  <a class="item mytitle ">My App Title</a>
  <div class="ui right aligned category search item">
    User Name
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.mytitle {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 35px;
    display: table-cell;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried to add the width="90%" in the CSS, but although it is able to make it centered, it pushed the Username, which I want to avoid.

Is there another way to make it centered?

Here is my current [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rudygunawan/85fenw7t/)

Answer (score 0):

Like This https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/85fenw7t/1/

```
.mytitle {
    height: 35px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 90px);
}
```